# Define a function $i : 2 \rightarrow 6$ that satisfies $i;f = id_{2}$ where $id_{2} : 2 \rightarrow 2$ is the identity function.

Tags: functions

Question: Define a function $i : 2 \rightarrow 6$ that satisfies $i;f = id_{2}$ where $id_{2} : 2 \rightarrow 2$ is the identity function. Is $i$ the unique such function?

I'm not quite sure what the question is asking to be honest. I understand there that is a composition of $g;f = id_{2}$ such that there has to be a function that maps the 6 element set to the 2 element set. I know this can be done by sending every even number to 0 and every odd number to 1 for example. However I don't think this is what the question is asking in regards to $i$. In the photo below I've noted everything I understand about the question.

[image]

Comment: Is semicolon being used for composition? What is "$i; f$"?

Comment: @Leo Yes I assume so, it is common in computer science to use that notation.

Comment: What is the function $f$?

Comment: Yeah, the module lead prefers to use semicolon, but I prefer the (f o i). Also $f$ was never defined in the question which is why I'm confused. I can upload the full question if it helps, although I don't think it relates to this whatsoever.

Comment: Does $i\mathrel ; f$ mean $i\circ f$ or $f\circ i$?

Comment: The latter. $i ; f$ means $f$ o $i$